# Using Touch/Multitouch in iuplua

Tags: lua, multi-touch, iup

Using iuplua 3.5, the following code should throw a couple of events on windows 7 devices capable of multi touch:

```
require("iuplua")

canvas = iup.canvas{rastersize = "640x480", touch = "YES"}
dialog = iup.dialog{canvas, title = "test application"}

function canvas:touch_cb(id, x, y, status)
    print("TOUCH!", id, x, y, status)
end

dialog:show()
iup.MainLoop()
```

Strange enough, this does not work for me and I do not have any clue why :( Does anybody have an idea how to fix that?

Edit: I have contacted Antonio Scuri who works on IUP and it seems like there really is a bug in IUP. He has sent me a new version of the dll in order to test it on an actual device capable of multitouch. I will let you know whether it works as soon as I can.